# Access Validation Failed Field Name in Spring Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, validation, thymeleaf

I am using JQuery Validation for my form validation.  My form errors are shown not at the affected field but in a div below the submit button.  Thus, I have a list of errors that use the `For` element attribute to reference the failed field.  I populate this with the `fields.errors` object in my Thymeleaf tmeplate.

Currently, I have the errors showing up in the error div, but I cannot figure out how to get access to the failing field.  Can you tell me how to find the name of the field that failed for a specific error message in fields.errors?

Answer (score 2):

check it [Thymeleaf Sprint Validation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html#validation-and-error-messages)

Comment: I noticed that when I was researching Thymeleaf validation, but you have to specify the field.  I was hoping to retrieve it from the fields or errors object.  Since I don't know what object I am dealing with in the template, I am kind of lost.  Do you have any other ideas?